# C: how to concatenate a number between two c-style null-terminated character arrays using strncat?

Tags: c, char

I have the following code and am trying to get a C-style null-terminated string after concatenating two C-Style strings and an integer in the middle.

```
const int NUMBER_APPLES = 6;

char Parameter_Complete[504] = "You have ";
char Parameter_End[8] = " apples";

char number[2];
number[0] = (char)NUMBER_APPLES;
number[1] = '\0'

strncat(Parameter_Complete, number, sizeof(Parameter_Complete));
strncat(Parameter_Complete, Parameter_End, sizeof(Parameter_Complete));
```

When I printf "Parameter_Complete", it says:

"You have < UNREADABLE CHARACTER > apples"

... instead of "You have 5 apples".

Can someone give me a hint on what might be wrong?

Comment: (char)6 is not '6'.

Comment: you could use something like: `sprintf(number, "%d", NUMBER_APPLES);`. You might need to make your number array longer though.

Comment: @LouisGo What is it then?

Comment: @slantalpha You may read bari and id01's posts.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you cast an integer into a char in C, it keeps its value, but is now used as an ASCII character. This means that `(char)6` would be equal to '\x06', which is not what you want.

What you *do* want is `snprintf`. This allows you to fill in a format string and put its output into another string.

```
... same code ...
char output[1000];
snprintf(output, 1000, "%s%d%s", Parameter_Complete, number, Parameter_End);
```

Or, if your two string variables are always going to be constant, you could just do:

```
const int number = 6;
char output[1000];
snprintf(output, 1000, "You have %d apples.", number);
```

Comment: I'm actually using the final concatenated string as an input to another function that takes a c-style null-terminated string as an input. For some reason, it doesn't work with the cast from int to char with `(char)`. I should have clarified that this isn't a display issue; the c-style string is somehow fundamentally different.

Comment: @slantalpha it works with the cast from `int` to `char`, just not the way you want it to. When you cast an int to a char in C, it interprets it as an ASCII code, and gives you an ASCII character equal to that ASCII code. Therefore, `(char)6 == '\x06'`, and `'\x06'` is not a printable character (it's ACK in ASCII). You can find a full ASCII table here: http://www.asciitable.com/

Comment: Okay, I think I understand now. How does `number[0] = '0' + char(NUMBER_APPLES)` work? What is the significance of the '0' before '6'? I thought you could only put one value in one character array index?

Comment: @slantalpha `'\x06'` means the ASCII character equivalent to the hex value 0x06, or ACK from the ASCII chart. It's one character. `number[0] = '0' + (char)NUMBER_APPLES` would give you the correct number, as long as the number is a single digit. This is because it adds your number to the ASCII value of 0, which is directly followed by 1-9, in order. After 9, it'd run off the end of the digits on the ASCII table into :, ;, and beyond. The best thing to do would probably be to use snprintf so you can use multiple digits and concatenate multiple strings at once - it does everything for you.

Comment: In C, the `+` operator doesn't mean concatenation. It means addition of ASCII values. It would be more helpful to think of a `char` as an 8-bit integer which is used by some functions as an ASCII value.

Comment: regarding the format string: `"%s%d%s",`  this will result in the three strings being jammed together, with no intervening spaces.  Suggest: `"%s %d %s",

Comment: @user3629249 the original post had a space at the end of the first string and a space before the second string. Should you add spaces in the format string, it would double up on spaces and look weird.

Answer (score 2):

maybe use sprintf or snprintf instead?

```
char number[32];
sprintf(number, "%d", NUMBER_APPLES)
```

Answer (score 1):

`number[0] = (char)NUMBER_APPLES;` is just 6 so it would replaced by ascii character equivalent to 6 which is non printable i think you should replace it by this `number[0] = '0' +(char)NUMBER_APPLES` the ascii character equivalent is '6'